# Regex select text inside quotation marks into groups

Tags: java, json, regex, format

I have a lot of lines in this format. I need to capture the quoted text blocks (including quotes), but the last block may be `null` (without quotes).

```
"1" "Melbourne is the capital of Australia."    "0" "Canberra is the capital of Australia."
"2" "New York is the capital of Florida."   "0" "Tallahassee is the capital of Florida."
"3" "Paris is the capital of France."   "1" null
```

Expected replacement after match:

```
{"id":\1,"statement":\2,"correct":\3,"additional":\4},
```

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: {"id":\1,"statement":\2,"correct":\3,"additional":\4},

How can I select these groups inside quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know there are exactly 4 terms:

```
.*?(".*?").*?(".*?").*?(".*?").*?(null|(".*?").*
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/9bfsSzbCLm)

It's important to use *reluctant* quantifiers, which capture as little as possible.

Comment: All works except doesn't convert null to group 4 if the line ends with null

Comment: @mind didn't know you wanted the null. Regex and demo link updated.

Comment: Maybe you know how to remove quotation marks inside unclosed quotations marks? Example: "Film name was "Pulp Fiction"" -> "Film name was Pulp Fiction"